# Why are the admin labels showing curly braces?

Tags: magento2.2

I have my development environment that is showing the labels in a very strange way after I've runned `composer update`.

I see many of the labels with the curly braces around... Something like this:

`{{{SKU}}{{SKU}}{{SKU}}{{themeMagento/Backend}}}`

here is an image of the catalog page.
[image: error]

I'm new with Magento, thanks for your help.

Comment: Check this answer, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071075/8308456

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you already installed the required php extensions.
(php-curl etc.)

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Answer (score 0):

The same issue in Magento 2.2.9 for DE store and after debugging an hour, I have finally solved the issue by following steps:

#### 1. deleted/commented generated folder

#### 2. flush cache

Answer (score 0):

In our Magento 2.3.3 the solution was to run:

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed pub/static/frontend
```

Then deploy static files again:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And finally clear caches with:

```
bin/magento c:f
```

Edit: This was a solution for same kind of problem in frontend. We did not have this problem in admin.